# SpriteKit view doesn't update in response to timer events

Tags: swift, events, swift3, timer, sprite-kit

In our program, there is a variable that ticks down based on a Timer, once per second. Our view update function runs whenever the Timer ticks, or whenever the user presses a key to cause an action within the application. Through print statements we can see that the variable is actually changing once per second, but the update only propagates to the SKLabelNode visibly on the screen when the user pressed a key. Is there some special "flush" function that needs to be called to push updates to the screen when there has not been a physical event?

```
func startGame() {
        ...
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func timerUpdate(){
        print("Before:\(mouseLife)")
        mouseLife -= 1
        displayNumbers2()
        print(mouseLife)
}

func displayNumbers2() {
        ...
        mouseLifeLabel.text = String(mouseLife)
        ...
}
```

Comment: No. 1, you don't want to use Timer with SKScene.  No. 2, what is your code?

Comment: @ElTomato Why don't I want to use Timer with SKScene? What should I be using to display a value that updates repeatedly in set intervals? I'll edit the code into the question.

Comment: It's better not to use Timer if you want to update the game scene based on a completed animation, because of the possible differences in the duration it takes to render frames. But it's completely fine for a thing like this where a Timer is used to notify your scene that (in this case) a 1 second interval has passed. I'm using a Timer where the user gets say 2 minutes to complete a level and it works completely fine. Similar approach to yours is used to display the time remaining without any "flushing". Can you see the label at all when the mouseLife is printed?

Comment: @JohnV What happens when you pause the game, you then need to remember to also pause the Timer.  Also Timers are not guaranteed to be 2 seconds every time, so your game also has inconsistency with how long one plays

Comment: RedEagle2000 the reason you do not use Timer in SpriteKit is because SpriteKit has it's own time system that is not related to real world time.  This allows you to do fancy things like speed up the game or slow down the game.  It also allows you pause the game without having to search for individual timers to disable and restart.

Comment: Read up on `SKAction`. Use these instead of timers.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes you are absolutely right, I didn't think of how easy it would be to pause the timer by just pausing the game. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

I've not the compiler now, maybe some function are bit different...

```
var mouseLifeLabel: Int = 5 {
    didSet {
        mouseLifeLabel.text = String(mouseLife)
        if mouseLifeLabel <= 0 {
              //Gameover func
        }
    }
}

func startGame() {
        ...
        let action = SKAction.block({[unowned self] in
             self.mouseLife -= 1
        })
        let wait = SKAction.wait(1)
        let seq = SKAction.sequance([action, wait])
        let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(seq )
        run(forever)
}
```